# Updating Adobe Reader

Tags: pdf, adobe

I have installed Adobe Reader, but I am not able to use features like highlighting, inserting comments, etc. in the current Adobe Reader while using in it Linux. How to use features like inserting comments and highlighting in Linux like I had in Windows and Adobe Reader?

Comment: There is no official support for Adobe in Linux. I suggest looking other PDF-readers. See that [software recommendation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1529/how-can-i-highlight-or-annotate-pdfs) for similar features. You can run Adobe on Wine for these features, read this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767937/how-to-install-adobe-acrobat-in-ubuntu-16-04).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I highlight or annotate PDFs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1529/how-can-i-highlight-or-annotate-pdfs) Highlighting and comments features already exist in the default Ubuntu pdf application (Document Viewer): https://askubuntu.com/questions/1529/how-can-i-highlight-or-annotate-pdfs/667017#667017

Answer (score 0):

I can strongly recommend FoxitReader as pdf reader. even on windows I use it.

it has the standard features of highlighting, inserting text, underline, arrows, comment, ...

Comment: It seems useless to install another application to do what the built-in Document Viewer application already does by default.

Comment: does the built-in Document Viewer have a cloud PDF function?

Comment: Foxit ConnectedPDF doesn't support shared comments and highlighting on Linux.