# How to natively install Adobe Reader in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-gnome, adobe-reader

I downloaded this [.deb file](ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb) recommended in the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767937/how-to-install-adobe-acrobat-in-ubuntu-16-04). The icon appeared in my Applications search, but when I click it, nothing happens. If I right-click it, and then click in "Show details" I get a Software window saying "Could not find 'AdobeReader.desktop'.

I also have nothing as output when I run `$which adobereader-enu`.

Does this really work or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found out that [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/851704/315699) to that [same question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767937/how-to-install-adobe-acrobat-in-ubuntu-16-04) suggests running `sudo apt install libxml2:i386`. This solved for me.

But I ended up uninstalling it because there were no commenting and highlighting features.

**EDIT**: I suggest everyone trying playOnLinux, it uses the version of Wine known to work for each software. (but still couldn't make powerpoint work, though)

Comment: You may try to install with Wine. According to AppDB it supports [modern DC version](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=3156).

Comment: I had problems with Wine not making MS Office Powerpoint correctly work in the past, although Word and Excel worked fine. But I think that I have no other option, so I hope I have better luck this time.

Comment: I suggest everyone trying playOnLinux, it uses the version of Wine known to work for each software. (but still could make powerpoint work, though)