# uninstall adobereader-en 9.5.5 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-uninstall

I can not uninstall adobereader 9.5.5.
I get always this message

```
    ~$ sudo apt-get remove adobereader-en
    [sudo] Passwort für felix:    
    Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
    Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
    Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
    E: Paket adobereader-en kann nicht gefunden werden.
```

Translation:

```
    ~$ sudo apt-get remove adobereader-en
    [sudo] Password for felix:    
    Package lists are read... Done 
    Dependency tree is set up.
    Status information is read .... Done
    E: package adobereader-en can not be found.
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: *How* did you install adobereader-en 9.5.5 in the first place?

Comment: Don't think you installed adobereader 9.5.5 with apt! Maybe with Wine or PlayonLinux; add more info to your post.

Comment: Guys above me. Please first check your knowledge just to be sure about problem :) More info about this package is e.g. here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/767937/how-do-i-install-adobe-acrobat-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @TomekPiechocki Well, there are other ways to install an application on Ubuntu. It's always OP's duty to provide all relevant details so that others don't have to do random guesswork (in this particular case method of installation as well as the correct name of the package were missing). Clarification from OP should always have higher priority than others '*checking their knowledge*' imo. (btw +1 on your answer :) )

Comment: @pomsky It was more meant for the second guy, as I saw he says false information. I don't know why I wrote in plural :D

Comment: That is also my point. If OP doesn't provide enough info to begin with or after being asked to, responders would have no choice but make guesses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that package was installed with apt earlier. It don't work for Wine apps etc.

Use

```
apt list --installed adobe*
```

to search installed packages. If you find what you want uninstall, then

```
sudo apt purge package_name
```

where package_name is obviously name of package you want to get rid of found with previous command.

**Edit**

In this particular situation

```
sudo apt purge adobereader-enu
```

Comment: after `apt list --installed adobe*` I get `adobereader-enu/now 9.5.5 i386  [installed,local]`
` then I typed `sudo apt purge package-adobereader-enu` but got the same message

Comment: Without "package-". Just "adobereader-enu"